# Is CiviCRM PCI compliant when it works with Authorize.net?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net, pci-compliance

Is CiviCRM PCI compliant when it works with Authorize.net ?

Or more precise, has an installation (using civi/auth.net) you know of ever reached PCI compliance by a PCI Assessor, or do you think it could ?

And, or, what additional setup requirements, like HTTPS, are there for the server configuration to get it compliant ?